# Seeking Advice on Gradually Replacing Existing Native Android and iOS Apps with Flutter-Based UI

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-frameworks, flutter-module

Our team is currently navigating a significant challenge with our in-production native Android and iOS applications. We've recently developed a new application using Flutter, featuring a revamped UI and several new features. Our end goal is to seamlessly replace both native applications with the Flutter version. However, integrating this new Flutter-based UI into our existing native apps without releasing an entirely new version poses a significant concern. We aim to prevent user confusion due to a drastic UI change while safeguarding our current ratings and download statistics.

We've contemplated two approaches:

1. Integrating the entire Flutter application into our existing native apps, but this poses concerns about maintainability due to dependencies on various third-party SDKs and libraries.
2. Exploring the possibility of integrating the native app into a Flutter application as an framework, although we are uncertain about the feasibility of this approach.

We're seeking advice and alternative solutions on how to seamlessly introduce a new UI experience without compromising user satisfaction or losing existing app metrics. Are there any recommended strategies or best practices to achieve this transition effectively? We'd greatly appreciate any insights, experiences, or suggestions the community might offer.

Thank you in advance for your valuable input and guidance.

We have tried going for an modular approach in the beginning it was very hard to develop it as standalone. so converted the flutter project into flutter application.

We want to know if there's a better way integrate the whole flutter app into native ios application with feasible and maintainable approach.